# Exception DI solution new query but I dont thing any new solution and help ı always retry questions problems solutions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, middleware

```
namespace Sozluk.Api.Application.Extensions;

public static class Registration
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddApplicationRegistration(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var assm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        services.AddMediatR(assm);
        services.AddAutoMapper(assm);
        services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(assm);

        return services;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXOXu.png)

```
namespace Sozluk.Infrastructure.Persistence.Extensions;

public static class Registration
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructureRegistration(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<SozlukContext>(conf =>
        {
            var connStr = configuration["SozlukDbConnectionStrings"].ToString();
            conf.UseSqlServer(connStr, opt =>
            {
                opt.EnableRetryOnFailure();
            });
        });

        services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();

        return services;
    }
}
```

Comment: when posting a question please make sure to ask a concise question.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more precise information about the problem and if it is possible for you add a code formatting

Comment: seems like he is finding hard to translate his problem to English

Comment: Can you please share your `LoginUserCommandHandler`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that scope for `IUserRepository` is not created inside `LoginUserCommandHandler`.

Please inject into your `LoginUserCommandHandler` `IServiceScopeFactory` instead of `IUserRepository`:

```
        private IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

        public LoginUserCommandHandler(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory) 

        {
            _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
        }
```

And next once you will need to use instance of `IUserRepository`, please create a scope for it and then use next code:

```
            using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                IUserRepository instanceUserRepository = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUserRepository>();
            }
```